# Flutter Image Picker to Image URL

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

i have the following code below. ive used image_picker package to upload pictures to be used as profile pictures. ive commented my previous code that uses an image url instead. my question is if there's a way to convert the images uploaded to images url, that way, i can display the profile picture when i get into the home screen.

```
// ignore_for_file: use_build_context_synchronously, deprecated_member_use

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebase;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:ibchat/pages/verify_email_page.dart';
import 'package:ibchat/screens/screens.dart';
import 'package:ibchat/theme.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:stream_chat_flutter_core/stream_chat_flutter_core.dart';

import '../app.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static Route get route => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const SignUpScreen(),
      );
  const SignUpScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpScreen> createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  final auth = firebase.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final functions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  PickedFile? _imageFile;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  //final _profilePictureController = TextEditingController();
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final _designationController = TextEditingController();
  final _companyController = TextEditingController();

  final _emailRegex = RegExp(
      r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+");

  bool _loading = false;

  Future<void> _signUp() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        _loading = true;
      });
      try {
        // Authenticate with Firebase
        final creds =
            await firebase.FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _emailController.text,
          password: _passwordController.text,
        );
        final user = creds.user;
        if (user == null) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Member not found')),
          );
          return;
        }

        // Set Firebase display name and profile picture
        List<Future<void>> futures = [
          /*if (_profilePictureController.text.isNotEmpty)
            creds.user!.updatePhotoURL(_profilePictureController.text),*/
          /*if (_picker.toString().isNotEmpty)
            creds.user!.updatePhotoURL(_picker.toString()),*/
          creds.user!.updateDisplayName(_nameController.text),
        ];

        await Future.wait(futures);

        // Create Stream user and get token using Firebase Functions
        final callable = functions.httpsCallable('createStreamUserAndGetToken');
        final results = await callable();

        // Connect user to Stream and set user data
        final client = StreamChatCore.of(context).client;
        await client.connectUser(
          User(
              //image: _profilePictureController.text,
              //image: _picker.toString(),
              id: creds.user!.uid,
              name: _nameController.text,
              extraData: {
                "email": _emailController.text,
                "designation": _designationController.text,
                "company": _companyController.text,
              }),
          results.data,
        );

        // Navigate to verify email page
        await Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(VerifyEmailPage.route);
      } on firebase.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              content: Text(e.message ?? 'Verification error')),
        );
      } catch (e, st) {
        logger.e('Sign up error', e, st);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red, content: Text('An error occured')),
        );
      }
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  String? _nameInputValidator(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Name cannot be empty';
    }
    return null;
  }

  String? _emailInputValidator(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Email cannot be empty';
    }
    if (!_emailRegex.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Not a valid email';
    }
    return null;
  }

  String? _passwordInputValidator(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Password Cannot be empty';
    }
    if (value.length <= 6) {
      return 'Password needs to be longer than 6 characters';
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //_profilePictureController.dispose();
    _nameController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _designationController.dispose();
    _companyController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', scale: 2),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: (_loading)
          ? const Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: AppColors.accent)))
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Form(
                  onWillPop: () async => false,
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24),
                        child: Text(
                          'Registeration',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                              fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                        ),
                      ),
                      /*Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _profilePictureController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: AppColors.accent, width: 2),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Picture URL',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          ),
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                        ),
                      ),*/
                      imageProfile(),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _nameController,
                          validator: _nameInputValidator,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: AppColors.accent, width: 2),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Name',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          ),
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          autofillHints: const [
                            AutofillHints.name,
                            AutofillHints.username
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _emailController,
                          validator: _emailInputValidator,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: AppColors.accent, width: 2),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Email',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          ),
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _passwordController,
                          validator: _passwordInputValidator,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: AppColors.accent, width: 2),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Password',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          ),
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          obscureText: true,
                          enableSuggestions: false,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _designationController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: AppColors.accent, width: 2),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Designation',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          ),
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _companyController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: AppColors.accent, width: 2),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Company',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          ),
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 250,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                        RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            ))),
                            onPressed: _signUp,
                            child: Text('Sign Up',
                                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                    fontSize: 21,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.black)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                        child: Divider(),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text('Already a Member?',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2),
                          const SizedBox(width: 8),
                          TextButton(
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                                primary: AppColors.accent),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(SignInScreen.route);
                            },
                            child: const Text('Sign In',
                                style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.secondary)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }

  Widget imageProfile() {
    return Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 34,
            backgroundImage: _imageFile == null
                ? const AssetImage("assets/images/profile_default.png")
                    as ImageProvider
                : FileImage(File(_imageFile!.path)),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: -2,
            right: -1,
            child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: ((builder) => bottomSheet()),
                  );
                },
                child: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.camera_fill,
                    color: AppColors.accent, size: 20)),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget bottomSheet() {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
          vertical: 20,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              "Upload a Profile Photo",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton.icon(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.camera_fill),
                    onPressed: () {
                      takePhoto(ImageSource.camera);
                    },
                    label: const Text("Camera")),
                FlatButton.icon(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    icon:
                        const Icon(CupertinoIcons.photo_fill_on_rectangle_fill),
                    onPressed: () {
                      takePhoto(ImageSource.gallery);
                    },
                    label: const Text("Photos")),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: source);
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = pickedFile!;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: so, what i’ve previously done is upload an image url (by right clicking an image and copying the url provided) to use it as an profile image. now, i am wondering if it’s possible for an image that i choose from the gallery to generate an url for me to use as a profile picture

Comment: For anyone that have the same question, one can simply use Firestore storage, upload and then get the imageUrl from there. However, do note that if account has yet to be created, additional coding is required for security. I hope this helps anyone